# Fancybox and google maps iframe, setZoom by -1 to fit contents

Tags: jquery, google-maps, fancybox-2

I've got fancybox working with a google maps.  However, the maps have several marker pins which when opened in google (and hence the iframe) are on the edges of the map.  This is no problem in on google but when loaded in the fancybox a lot of the markers are not visible because of the smaller viewport.

Whilst I could manually set this each time using z=blah in the url of the iframe it would be much easier if I can set it somewhat dynamically by simply setting the opening zoom level of google maps in fancybox to one less to compensate for this.

I've been looking at setZoom and getZoom in the google API but can't get these working as I'm not really sure on how to inialize the script, or where (sorry bit of a novice).  Something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'initialize', function () {
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1);  
});
```

....and I'm kind of going crazy after searching in google for the last 5hrs.  Any help would be really greatly appreciated!

Thanks for looking,
Nick

Comment: I'm trying this for example in my fancybox script:

`$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox-media").fancybox({

afterShow: function() {
  
    
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, "initialize", function() {
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+4);
                          
  })
});`

But to no effect :(

Comment: IF the code with the ` afterShow` callback is exactly as in your comment, then there are a couple of closing brackets and parenthesis missing.

Comment: Thanks JFK, I'll take a look now...!

Comment: OK, seems the code is okay, but the error in firebug is that google.maps is undefined.  I'm trawling through the iframe content now in search of ids...

Comment: Seems okay provided I change the callback to afterShow or beforeShow ie there are no errors, but it has no effect on the map!  Probably my google code (the eventListener) is off....